# How to iterate through records using SQL case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is the following SQL iterating the table 19 times instead of iterating through the 19 records inside the table? The point is to change the duration of each record using the case. but for each change, it iterates the table the same amount of the records in the table (it treats the tables as records). Really appreciate any help, thanks.

PS. there is a temp table being built up the chain hence the drop statement at the bottom but didn't want to paste a load of irrelevant code and obscure the question.

EDIT: if e.g. I take out the select statement inside the loop and just do a print, it iterates through the data and changes the duration based on the case statement, which is what I would like it to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMfXL.png)
With the way the code is now, it still selects the table, changes all the duration value for all the records to the first value in the case statement, then get a second copy of the table and do the same to the curation...and so on till no more value in the loop.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjrmL.png)

```
    DECLARE @eventDuration INT  
    DECLARE _cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR   
    SELECT  CASE WHEN sess.SpeciesId in (2, 3) AND e.ManagementPracticeId in (1, 6, 17)  AND jp.Id IS NOT NULL   
          THEN (CASE WHEN e.ManagementPracticeId in (6, 17) AND jp.Id = 3 THEN 9 ELSE jp.Name END * 7)
          ELSE MP.Duration END as durations
    FROM [dbo].[Plan] P
    JOIN [LivestockTypeDefaultEvent] MP ON MP.SpeciesEnterpriseStockClassId = P.SpeciesEnterpriseStockClassId
    INNER JOIN SpeciesEnterpriseStockClass sess ON sess.Id = p.SpeciesEnterpriseStockClassId
    LEFT JOIN JoiningPeriod jp ON jp.Id = p.JoiningPeriodId
    left JOIN Event e on e.PlanId=p.Id
    
 WHERE  P.Id = 507 AND  e.ManagementPracticeId in (1,6,17) and p.SpeciesEnterpriseStockClassId=MP.SpeciesEnterpriseStockClassId

    OPEN _cursor    
    FETCH NEXT FROM _cursor INTO @eventDuration  
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT     
   
       e.Id AS EventId  
      , e.[Name] AS EventName
      , DATEADD(dd, e.[StartDay], temp.[PlanStartDate]) AS EventStartDate   
      , DATEADD(dd, e.[StartDay] + @eventDuration, temp.[PlanStartDate]) AS EventEndDate
             , temp.FarmoperationMessage   
             , CAST( e.[Default] AS BIT) AS IsDefault   
             , CAST( e.isGhost AS BIT) AS IsGhost    
                   , CAST(@eventDuration as int) AS Durations    
                    , CAST(e.PlanId as int) AS Planid
    
           FROM #CalendarDataTemp temp      
           LEFT JOIN dbo.[Event] e ON e.PlanFarmOperationId = temp.PlanFarmOperationId AND e.PlanId = 507       
           LEFT JOIN dbo.[ManagementPractice] mp ON mp.id = e.ManagementPracticeId 
           WHERE (temp.IsAI = 1 AND (mp.InseminationTypeId = 1 OR  mp.InseminationTypeId = 2 OR mp.InseminationTypeId IS NULL))   
                     OR (temp.IsAI = 0 AND (mp.InseminationTypeId = 1 OR  mp.InseminationTypeId = 3 OR mp.InseminationTypeId IS NULL))  
           ORDER BY temp.FarmOperationSortSequence
              FETCH NEXT FROM _cursor INTO @eventDuration
    
           END 
           CLOSE _cursor   
           DEALLOCATE _cursor   
           GO
    
    DROP TABLE #CalendarDataTemp
```

Comment: What is the goal of the cursor? I don't understand the domain, but there might be a better way to do this with a set based operation instead of a cursor.

Comment: I had a go at answering below, however I suspect that the approach (using a cursor) doesn't actually match with what you are attempting to achieve.  Are you able to edit the question and add some sample 'before' data and your expected result?

Comment: @MathewPaxinos thanks for the  suggestion and your answer, I will try and edit the code but as you asked, I have edited the question so that you can clearly see what is happening, with pictures of the data

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It is generally recommended to avoid using a cursor.

Regarding the code as presented however, you are getting an '@eventDuration' parameter from the cursor:

FETCH NEXT FROM _cursor INTO @eventDuration

However you are only using it in the 'SELECT' portion of your statement, there are no filter criteria coming from the cursor, effectively causing you to run the select 19 times.

Pseudocode for cursors:

```
Declare Cursor
Get value from cursor
Loop while cursor is giving me value
   select data where column = value
   get next value from cursor
end loop
```